# Pattern regex inclusion special characters

Tags: regex, html

I have this line

```
pattern = "\S*\w+(\s?$|\s{1,}\w+)+"
```

It all works fine as it allows me to block the initial white space, and allow at those between the words, but I can not include special characters (for example: '+' &%) without changing this property. Can someone help me out ? Thank you

Comment: Is that a HTML5 `pattern` attribute, or a string-valued `pattern` JavaScript variable?

Comment: Why do you only allow `\w` not `\S` in the end?

Comment: html5 is a pattern, but also an alternative javascript can fit.
In the final part .. \ w +) + I allow to be able to write words separated by spaces, for example: "hello my name is" and the initial character \ S * blocks leading whitespace. I'm looking for a complete solution allowing even special characters

Comment: you can possibly do like `var found = str[0] == " " ? str.trimLeft() : str`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only `\S` matches special characters, `\w` only matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

So you could simply replace them to

```
pattern="\S*\S+(\s?$|\s{1,}\S+)+"
```

but there is so much redundancy then. Simplify it to

```
pattern="\S+(\s+\S+)*\s?"
```

or if really the only thing you care about is starting with `\S` then just do

```
pattern="\S[\s\S]*" <!-- or -->
pattern="\S.*" <!-- not allowing linebreaks -->
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an excellent alternative solution combined with "required" for the input field is not null

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a space split you should replace `\w` with `\S`.

And anyway having `\S*\w+` is sort of redundant, you could simplify with `\S*\w`.

But if you want finer control why not write out the whole range and replace `\w` with `[a-zA-Z0-9_+&%]`?

[Check out regular expressions for javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding if you want it to not find the whitespaces or the special characters simply remove the \S* this matches anything OTHER then whitespace which includes special characters.

`\w+(\s?$|\s{1,}\w+)+`

This means it would block the whitespace and the special characters at the beginning of the regex however special characters inbetween words would be ignored. for that i would replace the \s with \W for non-word characters. This would allow spaces and special characters in between the words.

```
\w+(\W?$|\W{1,}\w+)+
```

A great site to test out regex and where I was able to confirm this was [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) it's a place you can test out the regex as you type it with detailed information that displays what your regex will do as you type it. You can also include sample text to see what your regex will find in the text. the above regex when given: "  ! Test" only captured the Test and ignored both the ! and the spaces prior to Test.

Comment: The second solution is the one I was looking for, I return very useful, but I have discovered that they can not begin to write with a special character, for example: ('hello) and do not work when you have far more than one character, for example: (hello '+ ). How can I model my expression? Thank you

Comment: So do you want only the first special character or multiple?